# How to delay a Hudson build until its dependencies are built?

Tags: hudson

Our build consists of two projects, a library project and a web front end project that depends on the library project.

The Hudson jobs are configured from the maven pom.xml files and the dependency appears on Hudson as downstream/upstream project. Both jobs use the "poll SCM" build trigger and everything works as intended when only one the projects changes.

The problem arises when a commit contains changes in both projects, so Hudson starts a build of both projects at the same time and usually the web project build fails because it is using an older version of the library project.

Can I configure Hudson to delay the execution of the web project build if there is a build running the library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the web project and the other project located in a different area of the version control? ON the other hand you can define upstream or downstream dependencies and say only start if the build went well.

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail on the hudson jobs configuration.

Comment: You can simple add an upstream dependency and say hudson to wait until the upstream dependency is ready (there is a checkbox if clicking on advance)..just a moment do you have a multimodule build in Maven? You have setup different projects for library and the web project?

Comment: The "advanced project options" there you find "Block build when upstream project is building" which you need to activate depending on the direction of dependency you created.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed the "advanced project options" section